# Summarize MS SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server

I have the following records

```
       Jobsite  | UID |  Name    |  Rate | Amount | Amount2 | DateProcessed | FOrigin
       'X'        111   'Billy'    100    250      900       '2014-5-23'     '1'
       'Y'        111   'Billy'    100    350      100       '2014-5-23'     '2'
       'Z'        222   'Dan'      200    200      200       '2014-5-23'     '3'
       'Z'        222   'Dan'      200    200      200       '2014-5-23'     '4'
```

How will I summarize it based on UID, Name, Rate and DateProcessed? I still have to output dummy records for the ungrouped columns like Jobsite and Fileorigin.

The output should be like:

```
       Jobsite  | UID |  Name    |  Rate | Amount | Amount2 | DateProcessed | FOrigin
       'X'        111   'Billy'    100    600      1000       '2014-5-23'     'x'
       'X'        222   'Dan'      200    400      400        '2014-5-23'     'x'
```

I tried this query:

```
      select 'x' as Jobsite, UID, Name, Rate, Sum(Amount) as Amount, Sum(Amount2) as 
      Amount2, DateProcessed, 'x' as FOrigin from TblExample where DateProcessed = '2014-5-23' 
      group by UID, Name, Rate, DateProcessed;
```

But it still outputs the same records.
How should I summarize this? should I just loop thru vb.net?

**Answer**

"Subtle differences" in The strings you want to group by into is the key. An employee named 'Ann' is certainly different from 'Anne', that's why they weren't grouped together in the query.

What I did was I simply removed the Name and rate on the group by list, and used Max() on them.

Comment: Please edit your question and show what you want for the summary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query:

```
  select 'x' as Jobsite, UID, Name, Rate, Sum(Amount) as Amount,
         Sum(Amount2) as Amount2, DateProcessed, 'x' as FOrigin
  from TblExample
  where DateProcessed = '2014-5-23' 
  group by UID, Name, Rate, DateProcessed;
```

should not be producing rows that differ in the four columns:  `UID`, `Name`, `Rate`, `DateProcessed`.

You are selecting only one value of `DateProcessed` explicitly, so that is not the problem.  The issue is one of the other three columns.  My guess is that `rate` is a floating point number and really contains two different values that look the same when output.  You can try:

```
  select 'x' as Jobsite, UID, Name, max(Rate), Sum(Amount) as Amount,
         Sum(Amount2) as Amount2, DateProcessed, 'x' as FOrigin
  from TblExample
  where DateProcessed = '2014-5-23' 
  group by UID, Name, DateProcessed;
```

Otherwise, `Name` might have trailing spaces or unprinted characters that make the different names look different.  Or UID could have subtle differences.

Comment: Gordon, this is unrelated to the post. I am impressed by your knowledge of sql and ability to answer quickly. I want to get as good as you if not better. Can you please suggest some ways to become a guru in sql and rdbms ? Right now, I only know some basics and whatever I learned from amazing people like you. Would a certification in SQL server be helpful ? Thanks.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev . . . Some really excellent people are certified in SQL Server.  My own experience comes from analyzing data using many different databases (and other tools).  My purpose is to understand data (and what the data represents).  Databases are just a hurdle I have to overcome to reach that goal.

Comment: very helpful! Will try the max function with the rate. How will I ignore the subtle differences with the name? 

@BoratSagdiyev Please refrain from posting unrelated matters in other people's questions.  :|

Comment: @Malky.Kid - sorry for butting into your post. i was hoping for a tip or two that could help us all.

Comment: "Subtle differences" was the key. one employee has a name of 'Ann', then the other one had 'Anne'. Sheesh.

@BoratSagdiyev It's okay :) Thanks anyway

Comment: You are really too good in SQL. How do you find solutions so quickly .. is what I am really impressed about.

Answer (score 1):

If I were to interpret your question, then you're asking to be able to group by UID but still be able to output each of the other columns.
In that case, you will have to do a GROUP BY on UID, and performing some kind of aggregate function on each column.

Now, there are easy ones like Rate, Amount and Amount2, in which you provided that you want a SUM (aggregate) on those columns.

For the other columns such as DateProcessed and FOrigin, you could do a MIN or a MAX on them, it really depends on what data you want to retrieve from those columns because you do have to assume that you've collapsed two or more rows together.

It then gets more interesting on columns like Jobsite and Name. You could use the value of the first row, but then who's to say that Jobsite 'X' is "more important" than Jobsite 'Y'. Another alternative is to concatenate them. So if your first two rows collapse to one, your Jobsite column may be 'X, Y'. You could accomplish the concatenation using a user defined function.

Comment: Thanks! care to give an example of the query?

Comment: Sure, let's assume you have a function to concatenate called CONCAT, then the query may be:



select CONCAT(Jobsite), CONCAT(Name), UID, DateProcessed, CONCAT(Name), SUM(Rate), SUM(Amount), SUM(Amount2), MAX(FOrigin)
FROM TblExample
WHERE DateProcessed = '2014-05-23'
GROUP BY UID, DateProcessed

I also looked at your example results. I think you need to provide logic of how you arrived at Jobsite X instead of Y. Was it because it was the first one? Was it because <fill in the blank>?

Comment: It's okay, I got it. Thanks :) I simpkly used Max() on the name as well.

Answer (score 1):

Malky, Your Query is correct, is'nt it?

I copied your sql and tried, good your desired result.

```
DECLARE     @A TABLE 
    (
    JOBSITE CHAR(1),
    UID INT,
    NAME CHAR(10),
    RATE INT,
    AMOUNT INT, 
    AMOUNT2 INT, 
    DATEPROCESSED DATE,
    FORIGIN CHAR(1)
    )

INSERT INTO @A VALUES
('X',111,'BILLY',100,250,900,'2014-5-23','1'),
('Y',111,'BILLY',100,350,100,'2014-5-23','2'),
('Z',222,'DAN'  ,200,200,200,'2014-5-23','3'),
('Z',222,'DAN'  ,200,200,200,'2014-5-23','4')


SELECT      'X' JOBSITE,
            UID,NAME,
            RATE,
            SUM(AMOUNT) AMOUNT,
            SUM(AMOUNT2) AMOUNT2,
            DATEPROCESSED,
            'X' FORIGIN
FROM        @A 
WHERE       DATEPROCESSED = '2014-5-23'
GROUP BY    UID,
            NAME,
            RATE,
            DATEPROCESSED
```

[image]

Pardon me, If I read the question wrong.

Comment: It was, the problem was that some of the names in my table had very slight differences. I removed them on the group by statement.